# Proper Build Environment for Linux User-space Programs

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I need to build a Linux user-space program that includes headers from the Linux Kernel. However those headers in turn seem to use other headers and so on. So my question is, what is the proper/good way of including all off the possible directories I could require in my Makefile? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most user-space programs using the Linux kernel headers don't need to do anything special. `linux/` is already included in the default include paths, e.g. `#include <linux/netlink.h>` . Distributions will include these files as part of their stanh>dard developer package, for example `build-essential` on Debian.

You can also get headers specific for your kernel version, which is required when building a kernel module, but userspace programs will typically only interact with sockets and pipes and thus just need some structure definitions or protocol helpers for those channels (for example, Netlink).

Comment: I am learning fundamentals of linux kernel programming and thus have been building modules. Right now I am trying to build what I believe is called a "user space device driver" where I will be interacting with /dev/mem/ and custom file in /proc/. I would like access to some of the preprocessor variables and structures defined in some of the page-table headers for my architecture. What would be your recommendation for such a situation? Thanks again.

Comment: My recommendation would be to look into existing programs that do the same thing and see what they do. Unfortunately I've never done architecture-specific user drivers, only routing, filesystem, and accounting

Comment: I'll look around some more. Generally speaking I've found code excerpts but not accompanying Makefiles.